# Clean syntax for filling Bitfield structs from function parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-fields

I must send some data over a network where the package parts are not byte aligned. All packages are 8 byte long and an example package type might look like this:

```
union Packed
{
    struct
    {
        uint64_t a : 5;
        uint64_t b : 10;
        bool c : 1;
    };
    uint64_t raw;
};
```

So the first 5 bits are field `a` the next 10 bits are field `b` and the last bit is field `c`. Now I need a `send` function that can send this and possibly other package types. The function should accept the fields as parameters. The low-level send function accepts a single `uint64_t`.

**Edit** *As pointed out in the comments, it is not safe to read from `raw` after writing to `a`, `b` or `c`. To make it clear: this is also something i would like to change, but i included it at the top, because the union is used for all of my attempts.*

My requirements are:

- An overflow should be detected at compile time
- The syntax should not be too bulky (subjective, but i will show what i want)

#### My first attempt

```
void send_struct(const Packed& packed)
{
    raw_send(packed.raw);
}

int main()
{
    send_struct({1000, 2, true});  // conversion changes value

    Packed packed = {1000, 2, true};  // conversion changes value
    send_struct(packed);
}
```

The warnings are generated which satisfies my first requirement, but i don't like the syntax: The curly braces look superfluous and manually creating a struct first is cumbersome.

With some warnings enable i even have to use *two* layers of curly braces, because the struct is nested inside the union.

#### Second attempt

```
template <typename ...Args>
void send_var(Args... args)
{
    Packed packed {args...};

    raw_send(packed.raw);
};

int main()
{
    send_var(1000u, 2u, true);
}
```

Here, i like the syntax, but no warnings are generated, presumably because the bit width is lost somewhere.

#### Third attempt

```
struct A
{
    uint64_t data : 5;
};

struct B
{
    uint64_t data : 10;
};

void send_separate(A a, B b, bool c)
{
    Packed packed {a.data, b.data, c};

    raw_send(packed.raw);
}

int main()
{
    send_separate({1000u}, {2u}, true);  // conversion changes value
    send_separate(1000u, 2u, true);  // compile error
}
```

The first usage is ugly again: too many curly braces and the second one does not compile, because the structs cannot be  implicitly constructed with a single value.

#### Question

How can i implement a function and a safe package definition such that the following function call compiles **and** shows a warning, because the value `1000` does not fit into 5 bit.

```
send(1000u, 2u, true);
```

I actually only care about the call site. The function and union definitions may be more complicated.

**Edit 2**

Using variables for the function parameters <s>must</s> *should* work, too.

```
uint64_t a, b;
send(a, b, true);  // compiles, but may generate a warning
send(a & 0x1f, b & 0x3ff, true);  // compiles preferably without a warning
```

The software will be used on linux only, is compiled with `gcc` or `clang` using at lease these warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` plus the flag that allows anonymous structs and unions.

Comment: I dont see what is wrong with the first attempt. The curly braces are not superfluous and with uniform initialization the became rather natural for initialization

Comment: Reading `raw` when inactive is UB btw...

Comment: i should include in the question, that the struct definition is also something i want to change

Comment: You can't generally detect overflow at compile time if you're using variables (holding arbitrary values) instead of compile-time constants.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze that's why i added the bitwise and. Without it, a warning should be generated, but with the correct bitmask it should work.

Comment: The requirements mentioned in your last code section can't be fulfilled without relying on some very particular details of your compiler (or using e.g. an aggressive linter). You should look into writing your own custom bitfield that validates parameters like you want (or just automatically does the `&`), and maybe a user-defined literal alongside it (well, that's outside the realm of C++ 11), because anything else won't really get you there.